# Android - Get keyboard key press

Tags: java, android, keyboard, keyevent, android-input-method

I want to catch the press of any key of the softkeyboard. I don't want a EditView or TextView in my Activity, the event must be handled from a extended View inside my Activity.

I just tried this:

1) Override the `onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` Activity method. This don't work with softkeyboard, it just catch few hardkeyboard.

2) Create my `OnKeyListener` and register that in my View that contains a registered and working `OnTouchListener`. This doesn't work at all with softkeyboard.

3) Override the `onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` View method. This not work at all neither if I set my OnKeyListener nor if I don't set it.

4) With the `InputMethodManager` object Call the method `showSoftInput` and passing it my View. This don't work neither for raise up the keyboard, indeed i have to call `toggleSoftInput`; nor to catch the key events.

I tested all only in the emulator but i think it's enough. Why it's so complicate take a simple key event from a keyboard ?

Comment: And when you examined the source code to classes like `EditText` and `TextView`, to see how they handle it, what did you learn?

Comment: Study the source code can help but take too time.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For handling hardware keys and Back key you could use [`dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) in your `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

**UPD**: unfortunately you can't handle soft keyboard events (see [Handle single key events](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html#SingleKey)), unless you develop your own custom keyboard (follow the link to learn how [Creating input method](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)).

Comment: However there are problem with the character selected by the popup that appear on long press. For example if i long press the 'a' and i select 'à' both getKeyCode and getUnicodeChar return 0

Comment: Have a look at `getDeadChar()` method in `KeyEvent` class

Comment: Ok but this produce the character with the gived accent. The problem is that i can't know what key is press because of the 0 return in functions getKeyCode and getUnicodeChar.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Because of the problem with return 0 posted above. It just print 0 like my function do when i press à or è and other. However i found the solution casting the int returned by getUnicodeChar()

Comment: @vasart Dispatch Veent is not invoking for Keboard View Keys, It is invoking only when Back key is pressed/ Hardware keys Pressed.

Comment: @Roster, yes, that is correct. So how do we solve it?

Comment: @Nulik, see my answer below

Answer (score 18):

With the hint of **vasart**  i can get the KeyPress event. To make the keycode printable i have used the function **getUnicodeChar** passing it the meta button state then just a char cast solve the problem.

This is the **working code**:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent KEvent) 
{
    int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();

    if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        int keycode = KEvent.getKeyCode();
        int keyunicode = KEvent.getUnicodeChar(KEvent.getMetaState() );
        char character = (char) keyunicode;

        System.out.println("DEBUG MESSAGE KEY=" + character + " KEYCODE=" +  keycode);
    }


    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(KEvent);
}
```

Of course this work only with ASCII character.

Comment: In my Case , Custom Keyboard view is not responding to dispatchkeyEvent .. I have implemeted keyboardView and i would like to detect combination of keys like ctrl+c , Ctrl+v like that. How can i acheive that

Answer (score 4):

There are no option to handling key press events on soft keyboard (an on-screen keyboard) only from a hardware keyboard.

for more details: [Handling Keyboard Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html#SingleKey)

> Note: When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and
>   related APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only
>   from a hardware keyboard. You should never rely on receiving key
>   events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).

Answer (score 2):

When Keyboard is opened in activity your activity actually becomes foreground...
All TextArea or TextFields have their own mechanism to get keypressed from onScreen keyboard...
if you want to use onKeyDown() listner for virtual keyboard make sure that you set in AndroidManifest File under your activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" then onkeyDown() will work it did worked for me ...