# Show a dialog when press Home button android

Tags: android

I want to show a AlertDialog in my app (whether quit app or not) when user press Home. I read that Home can't be overrided. So, I tried to override onPause method. It works fine when I press Back Button. But, the problem is in Home Button. It shows the dialog when I press Home button, but it sends the app to background before I do any action on the dialog. Is there a way to do some work before it sends the app to background?

My work:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (clr.equals("red")) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertD.setMessage("Do you want to cancel your schedule?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                finish();
                            }

                        });
        alertD.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        moveTaskToBack(true);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDD = alertD.create();
        alertDD.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: See this link for an example. You need to use KeyEvent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273243/android-get-keyboard-key-press

Comment: Are you sure that override onPause can run fine when you tap back button??? I tried your code , when I tap back button the app go to background too fast to see your dialog...

Comment: @MengMeng Yes it is working absolutely fine.

Comment: onPause does not make activity closing blocked ... So how can you tap your dialog when the activity is closing at the same time?

Comment: @MengMeng I override it, so it wont finish activity unless i run finish()
   :)

Comment: @berserk nope, you can't prevent an app from closing.

Comment: I don't think so ~ @berserk

Comment: @MengMeng I am using it now, it working perfectly fine on back press.

Comment: @MengMeng Really sorry, you are right, its not working

Comment: back button works as fine as you wish no way but you override onkeydown and return true~~~ and you can only notice home button be tapped by recevie broadcast “Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS”

Comment: @MengMeng Can you please elaborate more clearly ? And can you post as answer please? :)

Comment: OK~ I can give you a demo if you want to prevent back key ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onKeyDown: " + event.getKeyCode());
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){                    
               // Do your work 
               return true;
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

you can use above method to prevent back key.

Do you see any APP can prevent home key ? None

You can only notice home key been tapped by receive the ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS

Comment: +1 for backpress. Can you tell me how to receive ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS?

Comment: But you can only notice home buttom tapped , you can not prevent it.FYI:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878038/is-there-any-way-to-exit-the-application-when-home-button-is-pressed-on-android

Answer (score 0):

That is very bad practice for usasbiliy of your app. And what behavior will be on long press of home button? User know that Home button is home button. Don't do this if you don't want to dissappoint users.

Comment: I know you wanted to post as a comment, but you can't :D
Actually it is not bad. The user want to detect whenever it goes to background and do some work before.